# calculating average but error comes as not a group by expression

Tags: oracle

I am writing one query for calculating average but facing error as not a group by expression. please help me out for this.

```
SELECT  mfg.MMFG_MFGNAME AS MFGNAME,
        count(case when sz.MCS_ID=1  then mtr.MTRM_SERIAL_NO end) AS count,
        round((mtr.MTRM_METER_CHANGE_DATE-mtr.MTRM_INSTALLATION_DATE),2) as diff,
        round((mtr.MTRM_METER_CHANGE_DATE-mtr.MTRM_INSTALLATION_DATE)/count(mtr.MTRM_SERIAL_NO),2) as avg
   from m_meter mtr
   join m_metermfg  mfg ON  mfg.MMFG_MFGCODE = mtr.MTRM_MANUFACTURE_CODE
   join m_connection_size sz  on sz.MCS_ID = mtr.MTRM_METER_SIZE
  where mtr.MTRM_METER_CHANGE_DATE is not null and  mfg.MMFG_MFGNAME in ('KRANTI')
  group by mfg.MMFG_MFGNAME;
```

I am trying to calculate average for meter life but error comes as not a group by expression

Comment: As the error (probably) says: `mtr.MTRM_METER_CHANGE_DATE` and `mtr.MTRM_INSTALLATION_DATE` are not part of the `GROUP BY` so they cannot be used in the `SELECT` without an  aggregate function

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

You are using non-aggregate columns along with your aggregated columns. You need to fix you query as -

```
SELECT  mfg.MMFG_MFGNAME AS MFGNAME,
        count(case when sz.MCS_ID=1  then mtr.MTRM_SERIAL_NO end) AS count,
        round((mtr.MTRM_METER_CHANGE_DATE-mtr.MTRM_INSTALLATION_DATE),2) as diff,
        round((mtr.MTRM_METER_CHANGE_DATE-mtr.MTRM_INSTALLATION_DATE)/count(mtr.MTRM_SERIAL_NO),2) as avg
   from m_meter mtr
   join m_metermfg mfg ON mfg.MMFG_MFGCODE = mtr.MTRM_MANUFACTURE_CODE
   join m_connection_size sz on sz.MCS_ID = mtr.MTRM_METER_SIZE
  where mtr.MTRM_METER_CHANGE_DATE is not null
    and mfg.MMFG_MFGNAME in ('KRANTI')
  group by mfg.MMFG_MFGNAME,
           (mtr.MTRM_METER_CHANGE_DATE-mtr.MTRM_INSTALLATION_DATE);
```

Though I have not tested it, But I think it should work.